# How to redirect SAS output to LaTeX?

Tags: compiling, sweave

I'm wondering how can the ***SAS*** output directly  be redirect  to LaTeX as we can do by using Sweave with ***R***. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give StatWeave a try: http://www.stat.uiowa.edu/~rlenth/StatWeave/

Answer (score 2):

It is already a while since you asked the question but in case it still helps I've done some experiments about this in the past: [SAS and LaTeX - A Perfect Match?](http://www.phuse.eu/download.aspx?type=cms&docID=587)

I could get it working fully automatically from submitting the SAS program to opening the finalized pdf file. It wasn't exactly easy but in the end I could produce any document or presentation directly from the Program Editor.